# facebook_session has no method graphCall

Tags: php, node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I'm using the **DracoBlue** [node-facebook-client](https://github.com/DracoBlue/node-facebook-client) and **passport.js** to authenticate a user into my app, then check if they are a member of a specific group.

I retrieve the users profile and access token then using the facebook_client try to get a session with the access token.

I'm not sure if the session being created properly because when I try using the method graphCall it throws the following error:

```
"500 TypeError: Object function (cb) { var session = new FacebookSession(self, access_token); cb(session); } has no method 'graphCall'"
```

A further source of information is found [here](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=0jgl4DK6WWD2xD79yLYY-BMcPHk&cid=kc1FaA-ZJN4&s=&browser=Default#L0).

Although not a php question. This is a node.js port of the php facebook client api so someone who uses that may have had the same problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
/* get the facebook client using ID and secret */
var facebook_client = new FacebookClient(
    clientID, // configure like your fb app page states
    clientSecret, // configure like your fb app page states
    {
        "timeout": 10000 // modify the global timeout for facebook calls (Default: 10000)
    }
);

/*
 * Define the facebook stragety
 */
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: clientID,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    scope: 'user_groups'      //Ask user to access their groups. Used for finding whether user is member of group
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('accessToken: ' + accessToken);
    console.log('facebook_client: ' + facebook_client);
    var facebook_session = facebook_client.getSessionByAccessToken(accessToken);
    console.log('facebook_session: ' + facebook_session);
    facebook_session.graphCall('/me?fields=groups')(function(result){
      if(!result.error)
      {
        console.log(groups.data);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('Error: ' + result.error.message);
        console.log('nane: ' + result.data); 
      }
    });

    console.log('profile.groups ' + profile.user_groups);
    console.log('accessToken ' + accessToken);
    console.log('refreshToken ' + refreshToken);
    done(null, profile);
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax was incorrect.

To retrieve the session I had to write the following:

```
facebook_client.getSessionByAccessToken(accessToken)(function(session){
 });
```

I'm relatively new to node.js and keep forgetting I need to use callbacks.